# Submitting a form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Some forms of mine are submitted with Javascript/JQuery, so no page refresh occurs.

But I've noticed a weird behavior with browsers between my 2 computers.
On one computer (and all browsers I've tested) my form submission executes as expected.
My other computer (Mac) it's hit and miss.  I'll submit the form, and it will do a typical POST refresh.  So the browser refreshes, and I see my button's text in the Url address bar.

-again, my PC's browsers do not do this.

Unless I'm going crazy, all I can deduct is that the browsers on my Mac are not executing the javascript properly.  But I'm more prepared to expect an error on my coding side.

Am I properly ensuring the form is NOT getting submitted with my Javascript?

```
<form id="norefreshForm">
   <!--more form fields here -->
   <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit Me" />
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({
       global:false,
       cache:false,
       type:"POST",
       url:"<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>",
       timeout:120000   
    });


    $("form#norefreshForm").submit(function(){

        $.ajax({ success:function(response){ alert("Submitted"); } });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Is javascript enabled? thats the first check

Comment: @coffeemonitor your code is working, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/gartz/aQKJg/ (tested in Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Turns out it's a browser issue.  I've tested across several computers and the major browsers, and it seems Chrome on my Mac is not playing nicely with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually some browsers you should do `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;` and I really don't know why. but it happened to me a lot. So, you can do this:

```
 $("form#norefreshForm").submit(function(){
        e.preventDefault();//should be at the very top 
        $.ajax({ success:function(response){ alert("Submitted"); } });

    });

});
```

Comment: I think jQuery normalizes `e.preventDefault` to work in all browsers.

Comment: @elclanrs, yes you might be right. but still I just use .preventDefault instead of return false for my ajax cases. just in case. but I really hope if there's some explanation from jquery guys!!

Comment: jQuery definitely normalises both `e.preventDefault()` _and_ `return false;`. (And if you return `false` jQuery calls `event.preventDefault()` for you.) Also, Mamdouh, would you care to explain why you think `e.preventDefault()` "should "be at the very top"?

Comment: read my answer once again. What I said that it happened to me a lot and that's how I solved it. and if you have any other ideas please share, because it is still ambiguous to me too :)

Comment: btw, it might be browser probelm and not JQ problem. just a thought!! @nnnnnn

Comment: As far as `return false`, _if_ using jQuery it should always work anywhere that `preventDefault()` works because of how jQuery handles it behind the scenes. If using plain JavaScript it definitely matters which one you do, which is one of the main reasons a lot of people use libraries like jQuery. Still, you're right that it might be a browser problem given the OP said it only fails on the Mac...

Comment: @nnnnnn - so do you think that same browser *let's say safari* might behave in different ways if it's on mac, windows or linux. **BTW that was my case once before**.

Comment: Yes, the "same" browser might be different on Mac. IE used to have that problem (back when there was an IE for Mac).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22434/discussion-between-mamdouh-alramadan-and-nnnnnn)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("form#norefreshForm").submit(function(e){
        $.ajax({ success:function(response){ alert("Submitted"); } });
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `return false` does the samething. issue is something else.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using jQuery only, return false should be enough. (Not 100% sure of mac)

But if you have pure javascript also written, in that case you may have to use `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation` also.

In case of IE its more different. Sometimes you will have to use `window.event.returnValue = false;`

So a combination of all these will do the trick normally.

So replace your `return false` statement with

```
if (eventObject.preventDefault) {
    eventObject.preventDefault();
} else if (window.event) /* for ie */ {
    window.event.returnValue = false;
}
return false;
```

This will work for both PC and MAC

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your form try not to use the submit button. Instead you can use a simple button and bind the ajax call on click of this button.

The reason for this seem like you are making two requests at the same time one by the submit button and the other your own ajax function.

Also the first submit fails because you haven't specified the action attribute for the form.

Comment: When the submit button is pressed it triggers the submit event which is then handled by the function the OP showed, which returns `false` to cancel the default submit. It should not be necessary to change the button type to make this work.