# jquery $.ajax post not working consistently in Firefox, but fine in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

First, I have an ajax heavy page (live chat and realtime data streaming through long running posts). I'm using [this HTML5 EventSource polyfill](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/blob/master/eventsource.js) resource, which creates long running posts to my server. In addition, the page also has [LiveChat](http://www.livechatinc.com/) integrated.

When the page loads, it creates 2-3 eventsource connections to my realtime data server. These are long running posts that will never complete. In addition, for LiveChat, it makes a bunch of ajax gets initially, and then periodically makes gets to poll for data.

So now the user clicks a link on the page, that triggers some javascript, and eventually a jquery $.post call to my server. However, Firefox does not seem to make the ajax call. I see it queued up in Firebug, but it never executes it and my server never sees it.

The behavior is also random. It will sometimes execute the ajax post, but most of the time it doesn't. It just sits queued up and never executes. Could my long running ajax posts be affecting this ajax post?

Works fine in Chrome, so maybe it's something with Firefox and lots of long running posts? Is this something anybody has experienced before? Is there some sort of max connection limit for Firefox?

**More Updates**

If I press ESC, it cancels all the existing ajax calls to the server, and when I click the link, it successfully sends the ajax request.

Comment: It is possible that something in your page could be affecting ajax calls, including other ajax calls. However, you haven't given us much to work with.

Comment: give some data so that we will be able to interpret what is definitely happening with your code...

Comment: you need to take care if you use long running requests (e.g. for status updates). depending on the webserver configuration the server is only able to handle a certain number of requests in parallel. e.g. if your server is able to handle 10 requests in parallel and you have 9 long running requests you have only one connection left. and if another long running request arrives your site becomes unresponsive until one of the other long running requests finished.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229827/submitting-a-form-with-javascript/14229906#14229906) for similar issue

Comment: Edited with more details

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan - I don't think that's the problem, and my issue is random.

Comment: @t.niese - this isn't an issue with the server, but with the browser.

Comment: @Garrett On [browserscope](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network) you can see an overview of the maximum connections per host, that the different browsers could handle.So the request is marked as "Blocking"? I just pointed out that it could be also a server issue, because when i did tests with different browsers, different techniques (long polling, server event, websockets, ...) and different servers and configuration, i saw similar behavior.

Comment: How about a [little bit of code](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) ?